# get value of input to button attributed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have input type and button, i need when insert into

```
<input type="text" name="bills_ID" id="bills_ID" value="2">
```

i will get id for this item and put it into here

```
BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=id
```

this is full code

```
<form id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="bills_ID" id="bills_ID" value="2">
    <input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="print" class="css3buttonblue"  onclick="window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='this.id, '_blank')" />
</form>
​
```

how can i put the id on this link BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=2 without refresh page

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
 <form id="wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="bills_ID" id="bills_ID" value="2">
            <input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="print" class="css3buttonblue"   />
        </form>
    <script>
       $(function(){
           $('#print').click(function(){
              window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='+$('#bills_ID').val(), '_blank')  
           }); 
       });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="bills_ID" id="bills_ID" value="2">
    <input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="print" class="css3buttonblue"  
onclick="window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=' + $("#bills_ID").val(), '_blank')" /> 
</form>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onclick etc. And use get method. Use this simple code and the variables will come in URL as query string.

```
<form action="BillsPrint.php" method="get" id="wrapper">
<input type="text" name="bills_ID" id="bills_ID" value="2">
<input name="print" type="submit" id="print" value="print" class="css3buttonblue">
</form>
```

You forget to specify action of form. Use this code it will work. :)
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(){
      var id = $('input[name="bills_ID"]').val();
      window.open('BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='+id, '_blank');
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#print").click(function(){

   var id = $("#bills_ID").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'BillsPrint.php?bills_ID=' + id,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
           alert(data); //alerts output from the BillsPrint.php page
      }
    });
});
```